# some problems implementing class templates for C++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm having some problems implementing class templates for C++. Maybe there is something wrong with my constructor, so I can't access the array in ArrayStack (int s). I'm a beginner, can someone please tell me what should I do? Thanks!

---

especially here：

```
template<typename T>
class ArrayStack
{
public:
ArrayStack(int s = 10); //The default stack capacity is 10

public:
T top(); //Get the top element of the stack
void push(T t); //Push stack operation
T pop(); //Pop stack operation
bool isEmpty(); //Empty operation
int size(); // find the size of the stack

private:
int count; //Number of elements in the stack
int capacity; // capacity of the stack
T* array; //The bottom layer is an array
};

template <typename T>
ArrayStack<T>::ArrayStack(int s)
{
s = 10;
capacity = s;
count = 0;
T array[10];
//T *array = new T[s];
}
```

---

Here is the complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<stack>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
/*Some types of brackets: {[()]}, 1 means {, 2 means [, 3 means (, 4 means), 5 means], 6 means}
* The algorithm needs a stack. In the process of reading characters, if it is a left parenthesis, it will be directly pushed into the stack and wait for the matching right parenthesis of the same type;
  If it is a right parenthesis and it matches the current top left parenthesis on the stack, the top left parenthesis will be popped from the stack. If it does not match, it is illegal.
  In addition, if a closing bracket is encountered, and the stack is empty, indicating that there is no opening bracket to match, it is illegal.
  Then, when the characters are read, if the expression is valid, the stack should be empty,
  If the stack is not empty, it means that there is no corresponding closing parenthesis matching the left parenthesis, which is also illegal.
*/
template<typename T>
class ArrayStack
{
public:
ArrayStack(int s = 10); //The default stack capacity is 10

public:
T top(); //Get the top element of the stack
void push(T t); //Push stack operation
T pop(); //Pop stack operation
bool isEmpty(); //Empty operation
int size(); // find the size of the stack

private:
int count; //Number of elements in the stack
int capacity; // capacity of the stack
T* array; //The bottom layer is an array
};

template <typename T>
ArrayStack<T>::ArrayStack(int s)
{
s = 10;
capacity = s;
count = 0;
T array[10];
//T *array = new T[s];
}

/* stack empty operation */
template <typename T>
bool ArrayStack<T>::isEmpty()
{
return count == 0; // when the stack element is 0, the stack is empty
};

/* return stack size */
template <typename T>
int ArrayStack<T>::size()
{
return count;
};

/* insert element */
template <typename T>
void ArrayStack<T>::push(T t)
{
if (count != capacity) //First determine whether the stack is full
{
array[count++] = t;
}
};

/*pop stack*/
template <typename T>
T ArrayStack<T>::pop()
{
if (count != 0) //First determine whether it is an empty stack
{
return array[--count];
}
};

/* Get the top element of the stack */
template <typename T>
T ArrayStack<T>::top()
{
if (count != 0)
{
return array[count - 1];
}
};

int main()
{
ArrayStack <int> stack;//The default stack capacity is 10
int flag = 1;
cout << "Please enter a bracket expression:" << endl;
vector<char> input;
vector<int> Trans_input;
while (1)
{
char data;
if ((data = cin.get()) == '\n') break; //After reading the number, read the separator (space, carriage return), and end with carriage return
input.push_back(data);
}
// Convert parentheses to numbers
for (auto i = input.begin(); i != input.end(); i++)
{
switch (*i)
{
case '{': { Trans_input.push_back(1); break; }
case '[': { Trans_input.push_back(2); break; }
case '(': { Trans_input.push_back(3); break; }
case ')': { Trans_input.push_back(4); break; }
case ']': { Trans_input.push_back(5); break; }
case '}': { Trans_input.push_back(6); break; }
default: break;
}
}
for (vector<int>::iterator i = Trans_input.begin(); i != Trans_input.end(); i++)
{
//If the first parenthesis is a closing parenthesis, the expression is illegal
if (i == Trans_input.begin() && 4 <= *i && *i <= 6)
{
cout << "Illegal!" << endl;
flag = 0;
break;
}
// push the first left parenthesis onto the stack
else if (i == Trans_input.begin() && 1 <= *i && *i <= 3)
{
stack.push(*i);
continue;
}
//If the left parenthesis is encountered, push it onto the stack
if (*i <= 3)
stack.push(*i);
//If a closing bracket is encountered, check whether the opening bracket at the top of the stack can match
else
{
//can match
if (stack.top() + *i == 7)
stack.pop();
// can't match
else
{
flag = 0;
cout << "Illegal" << endl;
break;
}
}
}
if (stack.isEmpty() && flag)
cout << "legal" << endl;
else
cout << "Illegal" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it not clear what your actual problem is. Also you should format your code with proper indentation to make it easier to understand. Finally your code is quit large, you should create a [mre].

Comment: In the constructor, `T array[10];` creates a local var. Try `array = new T[s];` to allocate space for the class member.

Comment: Don't forget to `delete[]` that array in the destructor of your class.